# trying to delete alert on Azure blob, created but not visible on next visit

Tags: azure, alert, azure-blob-storage

I have created an alert for the blob storage and it start sending emails so frequent. When I’m trying to delete the alert and not able to find the alert in the list but the alert emails are still coming.

I need to know why this alert email is coming or resolve this issue and need to delete / disable this alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you could leverage Azure Resource Explorer to manage your alert rules. You could follow the steps below to achieve this purpose.

1. Log in to [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com)
2. Input the keyword `alertrules` into the search box from the top and select the alert rule you created before.
   [image]
3. You could disable your alert rule by clicking Edit button, then set `isEnabled` to false, then click Put button.

   [image]
   Note: You need to switch to "Read/Write" mode from the top to do this operation.

   Also, you could click the tab "Actions(POST, DELETE)" in the above screenshot, then click Delete button to delete your alert rule.